# How to get # word from database field with mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex, hashtag

I have a database field name called "vCaption" in which i have sentences.
In those sentences, somewhere, there are words with # symbol at the starting  of that word. i need that particular word form that sentence. And if there is no # symbol word exist in the record then it should return null.

for example,

"my #childhood image from #1992 with my #Dad"

i have above record in my table.

What i need is only these three below words.

chilhood, 1992, Dad.

i tried REGEX and other mysql function but it doesnt get me what exactly i need.
Please help me here.

SELECT vCaption FROM tbl_post WHERE vCaption REGEXP '(?<= #|^#)\S*'

i have written above query. it return error

"#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Answer (score 0):

To select the rows that have words starting with a `#`, you can use this:

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "#[[:alnum:]]+";
```

But this only selects the rows you want—not all the words.

You could:

- try to transform `mycolumn` in the `SELECT` using [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to remove unwanted words... frankly, not sure if that's possible.
- post-process the selected rows in your language to extract the words you want. For instance, in PHP, `preg_match_all("~#[[:alnum:]]+~", $yourstring, $m)` would return all the #words into `$m[0]`

Comment: FYI added PHP code fragment for post-processing in case that can work for you. :)

Comment: yeah that will work for me but it is sort of compulsory for me to fetch that data using mysql

Comment: i can easily get those row but not those words. and i also need, if there is no word with # then i need null value in return.

Comment: My `SELECT` will fetch the rows, which is a good start. To get the exact words, I think you'll have to post-process.

Comment: `post-process means?????` I understand you may be frustrated, Pulkit, but that's not a great way to communicate with people who are trying to help you. First you devalue the ideas in the answer (`i can easily get those row`), then you scream... Remind me again how much you paid for that free advice? And all the good reasons why we should care about your problem?  By `post-process`, I meant get the rows, then process them in PHP. Sorry I wasn't able to help you, have a nice week-end.

Comment: sorry, if i was rude or made u feel bad zx81. but i didnt mean to do that. i just didnt understand so i asked straightly. i apologies again. And i truely didnt mean to disrespect ur or any of the member's advise.

Comment: No worries Pulkit, thanks for your kind message, we all have our bad days. Sorry I couldn't help, wishing you a great week. :)